# How can I get the result of a Count query in TopLink?

Tags: java, count, toplink

I have this:

```
ReportQuery query = new ReportQuery(OpenedFilesReport.class,
  generateExpressionOpenedFilesReport());
query.addCount();

Object result = getTopLinkTemplate().executeQuery(query, true);
```

As I can see, the result is a Vector and has one result of the type ReportQueryResult. Is there a smarter way of getting the result then

```
((ReportQueryResult)((Vector)result).get(0)).getResults()//.. do additional class casts/getter calls
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

query.setShouldReturnSingleValue(true);

Number result = (Number) getTopLinkTemplate().executeQuery(query, true);

Here is the link into the EclipseLink JavaDocs:

http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/api/2.2/org/eclipse/persistence/queries/ReportQuery.html#setShouldReturnSingleValue%28boolean%29

Doug